# Perl - Regex line that starts with "Out[1]="

Tags: regex, perl, wolfram-mathematica

I have a Perl script to capture Mathematica output, but am trying to find a good way to just catch the line starting with "Out[1]".

I thought I would just check `if ( $line =~ /^Out[1]=/ )`

What am I doing wrong?  Code is below, and then output of program below that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#perl testMathy.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

### Test 1: Print entire Mathematica output from calling Roots[]
my @charPoly = "-R^3 + R^2 + 3*R - 3";
my @roots = `echo \" Roots[@charPoly == 0, R] \" | math`;

print "\n***ROOTS (TEST 1)***: [@roots]\n~~~~~~~~~~\n";

### Test 2: Print line beginning with Out[1]
my $rootList = "";

for my $line ( @roots ){
        #take line that starts with Out[1]
        print "LINE:", $line;
        if ( $line =~ /^Out[1]=/ ){
            print "success\n";
            $rootList .= $line;
            last; #break
        }
    }

print "\n***ROOTS (TEST 2)***: $rootList\n~~~~~~~~~~\n";
```

Output:

```
***ROOTS (TEST 1)***: [Mathematica 10.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
 Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research, Inc.

 In[1]:= 
 Out[1]= R == Sqrt[3] || R == -Sqrt[3] || R == 1

 In[2]:= 
]
~~~~~~~~~~
LINE:Mathematica 10.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
LINE:Copyright 1988-2015 Wolfram Research, Inc.
LINE:
LINE:In[1]:= 
LINE:Out[1]= R == Sqrt[3] || R == -Sqrt[3] || R == 1
LINE:
LINE:In[2]:= 

***ROOTS (TEST 2)***: 
~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why is ROOTS(TEST 2): blank?

Comment: you need to escape the square brackets in the pattern. if there are spaces at the start of the line, add `\h*` to match them. You can use this tool to make your test: http://regex101.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square brackets are special characters in a regex. Try: `$line =~ /^Out\[1\]=/`

I'd recommend reading a regex tutorial [like this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to learn this kind of thing.